# How to add my own algorithms to ArcGIS toolbox

Tags: arcpy, algorithm

I want to implement and test some algorithms for line generalization tool in ArcGIS software by Python programming, but I do not have any access to its tool bar script. My question is, how can I add my algorithms into existing ArcGIS algorithms in the line simplify tool?

Comment: You can't modify Esri's core software, but there's tons of documentation on creating toolboxes in Python, and on Add-ins, and toolbars.

Comment: i dont wanna change the core ...i just wanna customize it with my own algorithms

Comment: Customizing an existing tool to change the algorithms offered ***would*** be a change to core.  Writing your own wrapper to exploit the existing methods and add your own wouldn't.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you show us your code so we know what you have, that way maybe somebody can provide you with guidance as to how to implement inside ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already saved your script as a ".tbx" file, just add the ArcToolbox sidebar, right click and choose "Add Toolbox"

Comment: You can add an appropriately coded Python script to a standard toolbox but you cannot save a script as a TBX.